# asp.net browser uses a lot of memory. Memory usage increases every postback

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, memory-management, browser

I have web application with updatepanels on it. The page has few gridviews on it.  When I bind data to grids and do a updatepanel .update() the memory usage of browser will increase everytime.
When I do this ~60 times the memory usage will increase from ~100mb to ~750mb. After 1-2 hours of page use the memory usage will be like 1.5gb.

It seems that my website will never release memory and always keeps increasing.
I have a few scripts also on page. With IE memory profile heap testing it shows that the memory usage will stay the same and no new objects will appear to memory. Still the task manager shows that memory usage increases.

I use session state but that should be on server memory? I also use viewstate but it's size remains the same all the time. I don't use tracing. I tried to disable all caching from page. Is there something else I should give a try ?

Is there a way to see what is in memory? Is there a way to release all client side memory from server side code or from javarscipt/jquery?
What does browsers store each postback on asp.net?

There is a lot of memory profilers to server side but is there anything for client side except the developer tools on each browser?

I have been banging my head against the wall with this now over a week and no solutions can not be found so I will appreciate any tip on this nightmare..

Comment: It must be a client-side problem, nothing serverside. We would need to see scripts and code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Aspx has ~3000 lines, .cs has ~21k lines and scrips has ~8k lines of code. So I guess no point of posting those. No one will go through of those. Just wanted general tips what more I could check..

Comment: Try writing code that does the minimal functionality. That way you can rethink your steps, debug and maybe post a small enough example.

Comment: @Jari, Please share any solution found